# CakePHP form submit not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I've just started working with CakePHP and I want to create a form that when it is submitted it calls a function in the controller. I'm using CakePHP version 2.6

The Code I currently have is:

view:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Tweet', array('url' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'postTweet'))); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->textarea('Tweet', array('class' => 'form-control','rows' => '3', 'placeholder' => "what's happening?", 'maxlength' => '140', 'label' => false)); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->button('Close', array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'data-dismiss' => 'modal', 'type' => 'button'));?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Tweet', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => 'submit', 'div' => false)); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>
```

PostsController:

```
    public function postTweet(){
        //check if post is being made
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

HTML on page:

```
<form action="/posts/postTweet" id="TweetIndexForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input name="_method" value="POST" type="hidden">
    </div>              
    <textarea name="data[Tweet][Tweet]" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="what's happening?" maxlength="140" id="TweetTweet"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>            
    <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Tweet" type="submit">              
</form>
```

The problem is when I click the submit button nothing happens, I've checked in Firebug and no errors are in the console tab, no POST is made in the network tab and there are also no errors logged to the error log. Any help will be great thanks.

EDIT:
Solved I had JavaScript preventing the form from being submitted Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you use -> `array('controller' => 'Posts',` .... See P is CAPS

Comment: Please post HTML you see in browser

Comment: I've added the HTML that I see in the browser

Comment: Its working properly sir -> http://jsfiddle.net/81uowjvw/1/  Same code .

Comment: I can see that it's working perfectly there but for some reason it's not working on my server

Comment: Give URL so I can check why.

Comment: Never mind solved it, there was JavaScript preventing the form from being submitted Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thats what i told -> If your HTML code works in HTML it should work in CakePHP too :) .  I knew some JS code is disabling Submit .Anyways welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use submit like ->

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Tweet', array('label' => false, 'name' => 'submit', 'class' => 'grayBTN', 'title' => '', 'alt' => 'Submit', 'error' => false));
```

It works I use it all the time .

The issue with your submit is `'type' => 'submit'` is used in your code and you also specify `$this->Form->submit` too .

If you are specifying Button with type submit then its ok like ->

```
echo $this->Form->button('Submit Form', array('type' => 'submit'));
```

But in your case you have $this->Form->submit.. So you dont need to specify it explicitely.

Comment: Yeah I've been trying different things and the 'type' => 'submit' was left in there from when I was trying to get it working using $this->Form->button, I've now removed it and still have the same problem

Comment: @user3758298, If your HTML code works in HTML it should work in CakePHP too :) .Please check <form html again ! And paste it in jsfiddle like i did and check if form posted

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Tweet','div' => false,'class' => 'btn btn-primary'));
```